# Is it possible to create a Ionic app that works on windows and android from a single codebase?

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, cross-platform, capacitor

I am planning on building a simple cross-platform video editor using Ionic and OpenCV for JS.
I have never used Ionic before, but feel very comfortable with Cordova (which now sadly ended support for Windows) which I believe is quite similar to Ionic(?).
I find it quite difficult to get started because I just can't figure out how to get my Ionic project to work on windows and android (and maybe browser) at the same time without having to use a different framework for each (i.e. Electron and Capacitor).
Is there something I misunderstood about Ionic and how this two frameworks are going to affect my code? Am I going to need different codebases?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @StackoverBlows could you please be more specific? I have read the guide again but still don't get what's wrong with my question.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic is designed specifically for this purpose - to create one code base for multiple platforms.

As per the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/

"**One codebase, running everywhere​.**
Ionic is the only mobile app stack that enables web developers to build apps for all major app stores and the mobile web from a single codebase. And with Adaptive Styling, Ionic apps look and feel at home on every device."

Capacitor is simply the runtime engine and also caters for all platforms.

You can use the guide above to develop your (single code base) app and build it for various platforms with the ionic build command:

```
ionic build // build for Windows
ionic build android // builds a .apk file which you can publish through Android Studio
ionic build ios // builds an ios version of the app which you can publish through xCode
```

Answer (score 0):

like suggested in **De Wet van As**'s answer, `Ionic` is designed for this purpose. you just need one codebase, but you are going to need different pipelines for building and publishing your apps, since they have a whole different procedure sometimes.
`Ionic` is not the same as `Cordova`, `Ionic` has a lot of styles to offer for your app to become nativelike in different platforms, and it's quite compatible with `Capacitor`, which is almost the successor of `Cordova`. you'll need `Capacitor` to create native build files for `IOS` and `android` from the one codebase you have (and some native plugins) and after that you are going to need a native platform to build an app from the native code that Capacitor have produced for you (Android Studio/Xcode). In the general scenario, they are pretty straight forward to use (you can check the official website for guides) and you don't need to do a lot of work or learn a lot of things, but you need them anyways, since the it's the OS rule to use it's own platform for building apps. Ionic now supports Electron officially and probably they are going to be handled the same as IOS and Android.

I hope this explanation was clear and helpful for you, if you have any specific problem about any part of the process, try reading their official documents first and then ask about that part explicitly.